# Stale read with Mongo and SpringData

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

We are facing stale issue stale read issue for some percentage of users for our MongoDB Spring framework based app. It's a very low volume app with hits less than 10K a day as well as a record count of less than 100K or even less. Following is our app tech stack.

> Mongo DB version db version v3.2.8.
> compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version:'1.5.5.RELEASE'
> compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version:'2.13.2'.

Users reported that in case of a new record insert or update, that value is not available to read for a certain duration say half an hour. After which the latest values in reading got reflected and available for reading across all users. However, when connecting with the mongo terminal, we are able to see the latest values in DB.

We confirmed that there is no application-level cache involved in reported flows. Also for JSP's we added timestamp on reported pages as well tried private browsing mode to rule out any browser issue.

We also tried changing Write concern in MongoClient and Mongo Template but no change in behavior:

```
MongoClientOptions.builder().writeConcern(WriteConcern.FSYNCED).build(); //Mongo Client

mongoTemplate.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.FSYNCED);  // Spring Mongo template
mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.LOG);
```

Also, DB logs look clean, no exceptions or errors seem to be generated on MongoDB logs.

We also didn't introduce any new library or DB changes and this setup was working prefect for the past 2 years. Any pointers would be helpful.

NOTE: It's a single mongo Instance with no slaves or secondary configured.

Answer (score 0):

Write concern does not affect reads.

Most likely you have some cache in your application or on your user's system (like their web browser) that you are overlooking.

Second  likely reason is you are reading from secondaries (i.e. using anything other than primary *read* preference).

Comment: Updated question- It's a single mongo node deployment. Regarding the, cache we already had set no-cache headers for flows we are observing issue, On top of that we also introduced timestamp on jsp's to rule out that generated view is latest and not the cache one.  Also validated that say student profile view requests are coming to server and returned with appropriate data. Also flow for which issue is, it's more like CRUD with no cache involved, insert fees record, get latest fees record, generate PDF and display, even there we are observing new record missing but visible after some duration.

Comment: The reason to change WriteConcern was that get writes result only when it's written in DB. Since Write and read are sequential, it was to ensure that read should be done on whatever is actually persisted in DB.

Comment: Write concern and read preference don't meaningfully do anything on a single-node deployment. You should probably debug your application.